# Game on $[0;1]$ about repeating decimal

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, game-theory, infinite-games

Two players play the following game. Before the beginning $"0."$ is written on the board. The first player writes any (finite) sequence of digits. The second one then writes only one digit. Then the players take turns. The first player wins if the number on the board is of repeating decimal type. The question is, which of players has a winning strategy.

My guess is that the first player can win despite the turns of the second player. I tried to combine facts that for any $m$ set of numbers $0.1a_1a_2\dots a_m$ is open, and that repeating decimals are dense in $[0;1]$, but I can't explicitly show the winning strategy.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The rules are not quite clear to me. If the second player can write any number in every turn, he has an easy winning strategy , namely writing down $1,2,3,\cdots$ succesively.

Comment: Sorry for being inaccurate in stating the rules. I have edited my question

Comment: Hint: suppose the second player is writing the digit at index $n$. Is it possible that there are two distinct choices of digit which both give strings of digits with repeating period $\lt n$?

Comment: This looks to me like a question about the irrationals in $[0,1]$ being Baire category, and the relation of that property to game theory...  So, from that standpoint, I think the winning strategy for player 2 would be simply: on move $n$, ensure the final number cannot be the $n$th rational number in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

The second player will always have a winning strategy if the "target" set ($\mathbb{Q}$ in this case) is countable: If that set is $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ then the second player only has to choose, on the $n^{th}$ round, a digit that makes the decimal expansion of the number constructed up to that point different from the decimal expansion of $x_n$. To avoid ambiguities, the digit can be limited to just two values, say 1 and 2 (so there's no issue with non unique decimal expansions)